# How do I publish entries with a specific category id?

Tags: categories, relatedto

How do I publish a list of three most recent entries within a 'blog' section that feature the category id '42'?

I presently have this code:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(3).find() %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I am having trouble properly implementing the .relatedTo() filter within this snippet, and all of the examples that I have read reference a category title rather than id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a CategoryModel to the `relatedTo` parameter, so its just a matter of getting the CategoryModel you're after. Something like:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.id(42).first %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(3).relatedTo(category) %}
```

Comment: There's no need to retrieve the category separately. [The `relatedTo` param](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) accepts the element ID (42, in your example).