# in a for loop, how do i only display entries of a certain category?

Tags: craft3

I see a few answers that look, hopefully, way more complicated than I'm looking for. I simply want to loop through entries with a normal for loop like:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('News').limit(1).all() %}
loop through entries of a specific category only here
{% endfor %}
```

Is there no way just to throw on something like .category('BreakingNews') onto that chain?

Comment: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/18951/9038

Comment: @piotrpog this is grabbing a category ID. I don't see Category ID's in my Categories control panel. I just see the full name with spaces (i don't even see a shortened camelCase reference name)

Comment: You can see category ID in Sections page. Please go to Dashboard->Setting->Sections. Each category has its ID in its URL.

Comment: @Kota.M perhaps i have this setup wrong. In the Sections page, I have Section Name, Section Handle, Section Type and Entry Types. If i click on the name of the Section I have Name, Handle, Section Type and Site Settings (URL/slug)

Comment: Could you move your mouse cursor on a category's Name? I suppose a URL shows up, and it has the category's ID.

Comment: @Kota.M I don't see any hover state, but if I inspect the link with dev tools, I see a data-id attribute with an integer in there. Surely that can't be the way one parses a category?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought it is section. But I suppose you can get a category by its handle or ID, as well as section. In Dashboard->Setting->Categories.

Comment: @Kota.M I figured out where to expose those Category ID's. In the Dashboard, select Categories and under the list of the Category Groups, there's a little gear icon that lets you check a box that adds and ID column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get entries which have a certain category assigned to them](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/get-entries-which-have-a-certain-category-assigned-to-them)

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('News').relatedTo(57).limit(1).all() %}
```

does work! 57 being the Category ID in this case. Thanks for the help.